# Possibility of passing propertie's names as arguments when constructing them

Tags: javascript-objects

I'm new to Javascript and need to build a function that produces arrays with objects inside to serve data to charts in react. 
I want to pass the properties name as a string through an argument to that function. How does this work? I tried out a lot and cannot find an answer online. Sorry for this silly question.

See a simple example code below:

```
var datakeyelement = "Existing Volume";
var datakeyxaxis = "name";
var datax1 = "Business Clients";
var datae1 = 45;
var datax2 = "Private Clients";
var datae2 = 35;

function chartDataGenerator(
  datakeyxaxis,
  datakeyelement,
  datax1,
  datae1,
  datax2,
  datae2
) {
  data = [
    {
      datakeyxaxis: datax1,
      datakeyelement: datae1
    },
    {
      datakeyxaxis: datax2,
      datakeyelement: datae2
    }
  ];
  return console.log(data);
}

chartDataGenerator(
  datakeyxaxis,
  datakeyelement,
  datax1,
  datae1,
  datax2,
  datae2
);
```

So the built array with the two object shouldlook like :

[
    {
      name: Business Clients,
      Existing Volume: 45
    },
    {
      name: Private Clients,
      Existing Volume: 35
    }
  ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the only issue I see here is that you need computed prop names

```
function chartDataGenerator(
  datakeyxaxis,
  datakeyelement,
  datax1,
  datae1,
  datax2,
  datae2
) {
  data = [
    {
      [datakeyxaxis]: datax1,
      [datakeyelement]: datae1
    },
    {
      [datakeyxaxis]: datax2,
      [datakeyelement]: datae2
    }
  ];
  return console.log(data);
}
```